# What could the problem be, if i am not able to clone something from Github?

Tags: github, raspberry-pi, failed-to-connect

Right now I am programming an i2C script to read some pH data from a sensor at work whatsoever. I need to clone something from GitHub but it always says that the server certificate verification failed. When I wanna visit GitHub.com via Chromium it says it has an insecure connection to this site. I can ping the page but neither open it in the browser nor clone something from there. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B with the newest Raspbian version with a working internet connection via Ethernet (or WiFi, neither creates a problem with any website). My workplace gave me a Certificate to install, if I want to use something else then Microsoft Edge. My thought was, that it is needed on the Raspberry Pi too, but I´m just not able to install it. I´m new to Raspbian programming and I have tried my best to understand the internet forums but I´m at the end of my knowledge. Does somebody know what to do? Or what to change?

Thanks for every answer
Matteo

Comment: Sounds like you are getting blocked by your company's firewall. You say that via Edge you can connect to Github?

Comment: i can connect to GitHub yes  on my workstations computer. But the raspberry has no Edge it only has Chromium. And still I can call the Page, the resolution is not good just some blue texts and Chromium tells me that it does not have a save connection to the site.

Comment: And I guess cloning on your workstation and copying the files onto the PI is no option?

Comment: i have solved it. thanks a lot for your help!